# are there any JS errors that may reveal DOM content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We want to start logging all client side errors to a server. The catch is that there potentially be a lot of customer sensitive data in the DOM that we can't know about or we would break our contracts with them.

The errors we want to log are browser or angular generated (from the exception handler), not from console.error.

I can't think of any errors that might do this, but thought I'd open source the question. Are there any JS or angular errors you can think of that would reveal content inside the DOM? The elements themselves are okay.

Comment: A JavaScript error could potentially contain anything: `throw new Error(document.body.innerHTML)`

Comment: Do you want to show the error or don't want to show the error?

Comment: Angular may disclose an expression you have declared within a template, but in my experience it never throws errors with messages that contain actual data, e.g. on the scope.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I'm talking about errors we don't throw. Perhaps a typing error we didn't foresee or a promise didn't resolve without a catch block. I understand we can throw errors containing anything, but can the browser?

Comment: @sdgluck so you mean data inside an ng-if="users" the scope.users object itself is protected, but the statement is not? What if it was a property on a specific user that didn't exist, ie. ng-repeat="user in users" and then later inside {{user.SSN}}.

Comment: I know I can keep trying these types of things out, I'm hoping someone knows definitively